# Unity Mask shows black content in world space canvas (Vuforia)

Tags: unity, gui

So I've built my scroll rect, like this reference tells me to do : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html

- -> Scroll View (Rect Transform with scroll rect attached)
- ---> Viewport (Image + Mask attached)
- -----> Content (Image attached)

[image]

In scene view it looks like I want it to look like, but in play mode it looks like this, which is the correct shape, but obviously not the correct content :

[image]

Update : My Canvas

[image]

Update : The Image is getting displayed normally, when I disable the mask.

Update : The source of this problem seems to lie in Vuforia (Image/Object Tracking library) since Vuforia appends a ClippingMask to the cameras

Comment: when the play mode is up, in the scene view where does lie your content? chances are that it lies outside the mask due to positioning the scrollable content

Comment: I checked that in the scene view and it lies still inside, but I noticed while debugging, that the same happens without the scroll rect stuff, so just the mask and it's content.

Comment: Could that be a problem with 'world space' canvas?

Comment: could you post a screen of the canvas?

Comment: should this be in world space? check for coordinates of all the objects to see if they should be visible by the camera

Comment: Yeah it has to be in world space, and I checked for the coordinates this is really odd